# How to optimize on a fixed-cost based on number of results?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, modeling, linearization, knapsack

I am trying to create an LP problem which is like the knapsack problem but where there is a fixed bonus/penalty based on the number of items chosen.

- There are 20 items to choose from with some weight between 1 to 20.
- Knapsack can hold a total weight W=40
- If only 1 item is chosen, there is a penalty of -3
- If 2 items are chosen, there is a bonus of 2
- If 3 items are chosen, there is a bonus of 1.5
- If 4 items are chosen, there is a bonus of 6
- If 5 or more items are chosen, there is a penalty of -4

While it seems like a simple problem, the bonus/penalties are constantly changing, and there are times that the bonus for 1 item is so high that it's the solution. My objective function is to maximize the total weight and the bonus/penalty associated with the number of items chosen.

I tried creating a Dictionary (call it dict) for my bonus/penalties and then having my objective function be `sum(items[i]*weights[i] for i in 1:20) + dict[sum(items[i] for i in 1:20)]` . The second part, the dictionary lookup, does not work and gives me an error so I must be doing something wrong.

Are dictionary lookups valid in an LP problem? Do I need to convert this to something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can linearize the objective as follows.

Let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether item $i$ is chosen, and let binary decision variable $y_c$ indicate whether the count of chosen items is $c$.  Let $w_i$ be the weight of item $i$, and let $b_c$ be the bonus/penalty for choosing $c$ items.  The problem is to maximize
$$\sum_i w_i x_i + \sum_c b_c y_c$$
subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_i w_i x_i &\le W \tag1\\
\sum_c y_c &= 1 \tag2 \\
\sum_c c y_c &= \sum_i x_i \tag3
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ is the usual knapsack constraint.
Constraints $(2)$ and $(3)$ enforce $y_c=1 \iff \sum_i x_i = c$.

Comment: Hi @RobPratt, followup question for you if I may. How would this work if pairs of items had bonuses for being chosen together? Example, Item1 and Item2 has bonus of 4 if they are both in the knapsack. Each item will have a bonus with each other item.

Comment: Add $4 x_1 x_2$ to the objective, which you can linearize by replacing $x_1 x_2$ with variable $z_{1,2}$ and imposing linear constraints $z_{1,2}\le x_1$ and $z_{1,2}\le x_2$.

Comment: If you have a penalty (rather than a bonus) for including both $i$ and $j$, you need to impose instead $z_{i,j} \ge x_i + x_j -1$ and $z_{i,j} \ge 0$.

Comment: @RobPratt, thanks for your interesting answer. Would you say please, what do the $c$ set elements mean? is there a simple group like $\{c1,\dots,c5\}$ to define five categories? or it is a nested set like a tuple?

Comment: Here, $c\in\{0,1,\dots,20\}$ because it is the count of chosen items.

Comment: @RobPratt, many thanks DR. As the problem is interesting to me, I have tried to write that. I defined items as $i \in \{i1, \dots, i20 \}$ and $c$ based on what you suggested. Also, with $b_c =[0,-3,2,1.5,6,-4,-4,\dots, -4]$. The problem is solved without any issue, but what I am interested to know is how classification the items w.r.t the items $c$! As the second constraint just allowed to choose exactly one item in $c$, what does exactly the classification mean? 

Comment: The index $c$ represents not an item but instead the number of items chosen.  For example, if three items $1,6,9$ are chosen, then $x_1=x_6=x_9=1$, all other $x_i=0$, $y_3=1$, and all other $y_c=0$.

Comment: @RobPratt, it now makes sense. Many thanks. 

Comment: @RobPratt thanks for the previous answer. Another followup, if I may. Let's say there are 10 groups each with up to 5 items. Each group has one special item and you must choose only one, let's call that group the "special group". There's a bonus of 4 if you take 1 more item from the special group, 8 bonus if you pick two. What I have tried is having `g[1:10]` which identifies the special group, then `a[5row, 10col]` which tells me how many items were taken from each group. I tried creating a new variable `b[1:5]` (max # of items) to try `[i=1:5], b[i] <= sum(g[j] * a[i,j] for j in 1:10)`

Comment: My goal here was that since I only care about my special group, I would multiply each group's item count in `a` by whether it's the special group in `g` and storing that in `b` to calculate the bonus. This introduces a quadratic constraint which is not allowed in my solver. How would you go about this problem? I'm new to all this so sorry for the poor syntax.

Comment: Please create a new question for this.

Comment: Apologies, just created the question, thank you again! [link](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7315/optimize-for-bonuses-within-a-group-knapsack)